# requestAnimation и очередность отрисовки

Tags: javascript, canvas

Здравствуйте!

1. Реализовал 2D игру и в Edge работает все плавно и круто, но в Firefox'e подвисает, сказали, что нужно сделать, чтобы раз-два момент и все отрисовалось, а не по частям, честно сказать зашел в тупик по данному поводу, как стоит здесь поступить?
    Уточнив у преподавателя, узнал, что память грузят анонимные функции - вынес в отдельную переменную без каждого нового создания, но это толком не решило мой вопрос. 
   Спасибо.
2. `window.requestAnimationFrame` - отрисовывает, но когда срабатывает `ctx.clearRect` не удаляет шлейфы за собой, а при `setTimeout` все в порядке, с чем это связано? 
   `this` здесь не важен же, все берется из замыкания.
   Заранее спасибо.

[image: Screen from Sublime]

Comment: а ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: @Jean-Claude , консоль все устраивает, ошибок нет.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame по своей сути отличается от setInterval лишь свое оптимальностью для рендера, но не более. Получается что Вы что-то не так делаете и именно по этому есть разница между работой этих функций.
Не знаю как сейчас, но примерно год назад мерил сам и в фф js работал в два раза медленнее чем в хроме. ms вообще уже давно лидирует в топе браузеров, хоть некоторые до сих пор его ругают по старой привычке.

Comment: И если я правильно понимаю код в самом верху, то Вы не правильно используете requestAnimationFrame, ей не нужно передавать время и её нужно выполнять рекурсивно. И если Вы её используете не так как нужно и при этом ещё что-то рисуется, то проблема ещё глобальней чем Вы думаете.